# Sort column in angular 'datatables'

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I created table

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%" datatable="ng" dt-options="options">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th> Nannie ID</th>
    <th> Name</th>
    <th> Last name</th>
    <th> Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="" ng-repeat='item in items'>
    <td><a ui-sref="admin.nanniesEdit({id:item.id})">id{{item.id}}</a></td>
    <td>{{item.profile.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.lastname}}</td>
    <td>{{item.profile.email}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Table loaded with first column order:

```
NannieID
id1 
id10    
id12    
id13    
id2 
id3 
id5
```

I want get correct order for each click reorder, and when first loading.
Expected result:

```
NannieID
id1 
id2 
id3 
id5 
id10    
id12    
id13
```

I added this code, but it helped only when table is loading, after click for reorder column, I got wrong order

```
$scope.options = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('aaSorting', [[5, 'asc']])
```

Please, help me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the `aaSorting` to `order`. Your code will be like:

```
$scope.options = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('order', [[5, 'asc']])
```

Comment: saved me loads of time

Answer (score 0):

You can reorder the array of objects with the **javascript** function `sort`

```
$scope.asc = false;
$scope.reorder = function(direction){
    items.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a.id - b.id;
    });
    if(asc){
        items.reverse();
        asc = false;
    }
}
```

And add a button with an `ng-click` calling `reorder`

```
<button ng-click="$scope.reorder()">Reorder</button>
```

Every time you press the `Reorder` button, your list is going to switch from `Asc Order` and `Desc Order`