# How to change the scope variable when sorting applied on the table?

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

I am using Angular Datatable with ng-repeat, where all columns can be sorted. After sorting, I want the scope variable should be changed.. Can it be achieved?

simple example is below: In my case I'm using array of `JSON` objects

```
$scope.names = ['XYZ', 'DEF', 'ABC', 'IJK'];
```

After datatable sorting applied on name field, the value of name filed should be changed to the following:

```
$scope.names = ['ABC', 'DEF', 'IJK', 'XYZ'];
```

Comment: DT only sort internally, it does not effect the underlying dataset (whatever that is) and it is the same deal with AngularJS. No repeat, orderBy, limit or similar changes the data. But you can extract the current sorted dataset from DT if you want.

Comment: Can you please tell me how it can be achieved?

Comment: Perhaps, if I know how you create the  Angular Datatable. You must use a `dt-instance`.

Comment: Similar example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441456/sort-column-in-angular-datatables). Please look otherwise you have to post your code or provide a plunkr.

Comment: I'm using the code from the below link...http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/#!/angularWay            If I sort the table, I need data to be sorted accordingly... Anyways I will post my code in some time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is working... Thanks @davidkonrad for the hint on dtInstance

```
 var sortedTableArray = [];
 var sortedJSON = []       
 DTInstances.getList().then(function(dtInstances) {
sortedTableArray.push(dtInstances.viewTable.DataTable.context[0].aiDisplay)

              sortedJSON = _.sortBy(unsortedList, function(obj){

                    return _.indexOf(_.toArray(sortedTableArray[0]), obj.id);
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try orderBy filter. For eg,

```
ng-repeat="[{doc: 'bbb'}, {doc: 'aaa'}, {doc: 'ccc'}] | orderBy:'doc'"
```

would result in `[{doc: 'aaa'}, {doc: 'bbb'}, {doc: 'ccc'}]`

In your case you have strings instead of objects in array so I guess you can write  `| orderBy`